# Short code samples, solving interesting problems (in multiple languages)

Tags: programming-languages, sample

recently I've found an interesting  sample "spell checker in 21 lines of code" by head of Google research department - Peter Norvig http://www.norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Although it's an very interesting stuff by itself, it's also interesting to see how the same problem are solved in different languages!

Do You know more of such samples (solved in multiple languages)? Please post link here.

Comment: Not a real question since there cannot be a *right* answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have look at [PLEAC](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/) the same problems solved in numerous languages.

Currently these languages are included:

- perl
- groovy
- ocaml
- python
- ruby
- guile
- commonlisp
- rexx
- tcl
- pike
- php
- haskell
- merd
- picolisp
- ada
- haskell-on-steroids
- java
- cposix
- pliant
- c++
- factor
- smalltalk
- forth
- erlang
- R
- objective-c
- masd
- bash
- nasm
- go

Answer (score 1):

Check [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category%3aProgramming_Tasks), it's a huge collection of tasks solved in different languages.

Answer (score 1):

The website [99 Bottles of Beer](http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/) holds implementations of the lyrics of the song *99 Bottles of Beer* in 1434 programming languages.

[PLEAC](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/) contains implementations in several languages of the common programming problems presented in the [Perl Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922433).

The [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Main_Page) also presents solutions to the same task in many different languages.